# How to extract area of interest in the image while the boundary is not obvious

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

[image: This is the initial image. The square part which has different contrast is the area of interest, which I want to get the information for machine learning.]

[image: I tried sobel kernels. The boundaries can be seen]

Are there ways to just extract the area of interest (the square light part in the red circle in the original image)? That means I need to get the coordinates of the edge and then masking the image outside the boundaries. I don't know how to do that. Could anyone help? Thanks!

```python
#define horizontal and Vertical sobel kernels
Gx = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],[-2, 0, 2],[-1, 0, 1]])
Gy = np.array([[-1, -2, -1],[0, 0, 0],[1, 2, 1]])

#define kernal convolution function
# with image X and filter F
def convolve(X, F):
    # height and width of the image
    X_height = X.shape[0]
    X_width = X.shape[3]

    # height and width of the filter
    F_height = F.shape[0]
    F_width = F.shape[1]

    H = (F_height - 1) // 2
    W = (F_width - 1) // 2

    #output numpy matrix with height and width
    out = np.zeros((X_height, X_width))
    #iterate over all the pixel of image X
    for i in np.arange(H, X_height-H):
        for j in np.arange(W, X_width-W):
            sum = 0
            #iterate over the filter
            for k in np.arange(-H, H+1):
                for l in np.arange(-W, W+1):
                    #get the corresponding value from image and filter
                    a = X[i+k, j+l]
                    w = F[H+k, W+l]
                    sum += (w * a)
            out[i,j] = sum
    #return convolution  
    return out

#normalizing the vectors
sob_x = convolve(image, Gx) / 8.0
sob_y = convolve(image, Gy) / 8.0

#calculate the gradient magnitude of vectors
sob_out = np.sqrt(np.power(sob_x, 2) + np.power(sob_y, 2))
# mapping values from 0 to 255
sob_out = (sob_out / np.max(sob_out)) * 255

plt.imshow(sob_out, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.show()
```

Comment: you'll want some kind of texture analysis. when in doubt, train a U-Net to do it.

Comment: @ Christoph Rackwitz Thanks for the comments! U-Net will detect the boundaries and also make the area of interest invisible. Looks like U-NET only work on Linux systems.

Comment: false assertions. u-net is to be trained and run, not used as is, and you can do the training and inference on any operating system, because that merely depends on what implementation (for pytorch? tensorflow?) you are using. -- it's also not meant to detect boundaries (the lines around things) but to give you a segmentation (per pixel labels). it does not make anything "invisible". it's a mask. you're supposed to use the mask.